# Including global package into a virtualenv that has been created with --no-site-packages

Tags: python, virtualenv, easy-install, pip

I'd usually prefer to create virtualenvs with `--no-site-packages` option for more isolation, and also because default python global packages includes quite a lot of packages, and usually most of them are not needed.
However I'd still want to keep a few select packages in global, like `PIL` or `psycopg2`. Is there a good way to include them into the `virtualenv`, that can also be automated easily?

Comment: Related: [Installing certain packages using virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434407/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) and you might be able to use the [postmkvirtualenv](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/scripts.html#scripts-postmkvirtualenv) script to automatically create symlinks in the new virtualenv sitepackages directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
cdsitepackages
ln -s /path/to/system/site-packages/package-name
cdvirtualenv
```

Comment: Forgot about this question, but I ended up doing exactly this.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [virtualenvwrapper](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper), the shell command `add2virtualenv` should be present in an active virtualenv.  Use:

```
add2virtualenv /path/to/package
```

to add an entry to the PTH file `_virtualenv_path_extensions.pth` in your virtualenv site-packages.

The benefit of using add2virtualenv rather than creating symlinks yourself, is that you can remove the package from being importable by commenting out its line in the PTH file.  This makes it easier to check your code's validity against several versions of a library on which it depends.

Comment: Yes, I agree this is now the better way. I'm pretty sure it wasn't available a couple years ago though.

Comment: Probably it wasn't available.  I am certainly a big fan of virtualenvwrapper for little useful things like that.  Of course you could also do it manually, by writing your own PTH file.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually tried this with those specific packages, but I would guess that a simple symlink from the global site-packages into the virtualenv's site-packages might work, and this is easily scriptable.