# Can I cherry-pick packages from site-packages in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, virtualenv, pip

So I'm working on migrating a Django project to virtualenv/pip. I'd like to use --no-site-packages for the most control over the environment, but the sticking point appears to be PIL. Given that PIL is notoriously difficult to install with pip, especially as there are Windows users on the team, I'd rather use that *one* package from site-packages, without pulling everything else in. Is there a sane way to do this? If I have to use `pip install PIL`, the instructions for setting up a new checkout will wind up *longer*, not shorter …

Comment: Duplicate: [Including global package into a virtualenv that has been created with --no-site-packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767382/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a `PIL.pth` file in the virtualenv's site-packages (or wherever on the sys.path) to add the name of the PIL directory, which will be appended to `sys.path`. Here on linux PIL already uses a .pth file, so it's just a matter of copying it and making the path absolute.

Comment: Okay, that works. Wish I could find a better way, but that's not so bad for a workaround.